# Turning a certain age in Spanish

Tags: vocabulario, gramática

I know **tener** is the verb used when talking about one’s age. So the following translation makes perfect sense:

**Tengo treinta años.** *I am 30 years old.*

But what if I want to translate the following sentences?

*I am turning 30.
I just turned 30.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I am turning 30.** *Voy a cumplir treinta años.*

**I just turned 30.** *Acabo de cumplir treinta años.*